# BC30456 Visual Basic AND VB.NET 'openFileDialog1' is not a member of windowsapp1.my

Tags: vb.net

Hello I am very new to Visual Basic and have almost no clue what I am doing. I have encountered an issue saying the following.

> openFileDialog1 is not a member of windowsapp1.my

I can not seem to fix it. Here is my code:

```
Public Class Form1
  Private Sub Form1_Load()
    Dim OpenFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog
    My.openFileDialog1.Title = "Please select a DB file"
    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "DB Files|*.extensionHERE"
  End Sub
End Class
```

I have tried to no avail to fix this and so I hope that some one can help, thanks!

Comment: You declared `OpenFileDialog1` just the line before then you try to reference it as `my.OpenFileDialog1`?  Why?  Just a tiny bit of deductive reasoning tells you that if it is complaining about `my.OpenFileDialog1` but all the `OpenFileDialog1` references are ok, then `my` is the problem

Comment: Most of the guides that I could find said to do that, so I tried but it did not work

Comment: Thank you, as I said I have 0 experience

Comment: "Most of the guides that I could find said to do that". I can guarantee you that they didn't. It may be that they used names like `myOpenFileDialog` for the variable in the first place but I've never once seen anything that suggests doing what you did.  I'd be interested to see a link to one that you think did suggest that.

Comment: Perhaps you're confusing the [`Me` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/me-my-mybase-and-myclass#me) with the [`My` namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/customizing-extending-my/extending-the-my-namespace)? If that's the case, `Me` is what you're looking for but in order to use it, you'd need to declare your variable at the class level. See [Variable Declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/variables/variable-declaration)

Comment: thanks @Ahmed Abdelhameed I was doing exactly that

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mis-reading what the examples are saying. When you read tutorial/example code, where it lists "OpenFileDialog1," for example (or DataGridView1, etc.) that refers to whatever name *you* are using for your particular OpenFileDialog1 control. If you had multiple openfiledialogs in your code, having them all named OpenFileDialog*N* can get confusing it a larger application. Using a meaningful name is a good practice.

Using the "My" isn't necessary in your code snippet. In VB, the "My" refers to a namespace indicating the system on which the application runs. Since all your code is doing is opening a file dialog, that isn't necessary.

Check out this handy doc by MS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/development-with-my/index